# Northern earth presented bigger, than southern on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geography

Note: This not programming question,

Just, for me , google maps are incorrect

I am about that, map shows northern earth bigger than southern, for example, in google maps, Greenland is even bigger than South america continent

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planar projection problem. Mapping a 3D coordinate system (the globe) on a 2D coordinate system means you have to distort some properties. You lose one or more of size, direction, distance and shape.

The choice of default plane projection by Google Maps is close to Mercator perhaps, so size and shape are not preserved but direction (nautical) is. So rather than incorrect, it is a choice.

The default projection can actually be changed with Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple

You can choose which properties you want to preserve depending on choice of projection. Like in the one below, Greenland's size is closer to its true value:

[image: Bonus pic from the API docs]